# PHP exec hangs on page load, but works after refresh

Tags: php, exec

Why doesn't PHP exec() work on the first page load? 
I'm executing a python script via PHP using the following line:

```
exec("python suggester.py " . $query_plus . " " . $location, $output);
```

Most of the time this works fine, but on the initial load of my page (suggester.promediacorp.com) the POST request sits in waiting/pending for almost a minute until it finally returns a response. If the page is refreshed, or another query runs after, it works perfectly.

I'm almost 100% sure the issue is related to exec(), because when I remove that code I get my response immediately. Additionally, the issue persists even if the python file has no contents.

Comment: I'd guess it caches something computationally heavy the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was an issue with php's error logging that was echoed before my script finished running.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have arguments escaped propperly. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php